# Finding the geometric series of the fraction

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series

I am confused as to how to turn a fraction into a sum using geometric series.

I have $\frac{z+2}{(z-1)(z-4)}=\frac{2}{z-4}+\frac{-1}{z-1}$

I do not know how I turn the last 2 fractions into geometric series and write them as sum. Can someone please help me?

Comment: If you don't know how to turn $\frac1{1-x}$ into a geometric sum, refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series. If you do know then $\frac2{z-4} = -\frac24\cdot\cfrac1{1-\frac z4}$ and replace $x$ with $\frac z4$ in $\frac1{1-x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have previously seen that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n =\frac{1}{1-z}, \;\;|z|<1$$

Then you may use $\frac{2}{z-4}=-\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{1-z/4}$ and $\frac{-1}{z-1}=\frac{1}{1-z}$.